# How to load same page on refresh in angularjs?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

i have an application  written in nodejs and angularjs . In index page  bottom of  there is an   hyperlink text.when i click on that hyper link page is loading but when i refresh same page it give 404 error .

Comment: Without any code or any indication of how you are using node.js, this will be tough to answer.

Comment: So you use angular.js with html5 mode, and you have to set your server to return `index` page for any route.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page, you are telling the http server to handle a `GET` request for some resource that matches the hyperlink address.

Assume this address is `path/to/resource`.

When the server receives that request, it looks for a static resource or a handler that matches that path. If it does not find one, it returns a 404.

Assuming that the hyperlinked resource is something withing your angular app, you need to server the index.html page again **regardless** of what is requested. This will allow the angular app to bootstrap, parse the route, and go through its own routing to reload that page.

Comment: thank you some much for your reply .can i have an example please

Comment: @codeghost what mvc framework are you using with node?

Comment: yeah.i am using nodejs on server side

Comment: @codeghost but what are you using with node to handle http rest requests?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Express then this code would do the trick:

```
var app = require('express');
app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
    return next();
});
```

Now every request will return index file and Angular will do the rest.